# DataFrame.to_csv() excesses values from a cell

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, csv

I've got some troubles saving a dataframe as a csv.
One of the columns - "skus" - contains in each cell a list of strings.
If I try to visualize it in a notebook, that's the result:
[image]

But if I try to save it as a csv,

```
output.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

one of the cells exceeded its content and that's what I see:
[image]

This cell contains a list of 2456 strings.
Is there any limit in the dimension of the cells in an csv file, maybe?

Thank you

EDIT:

My goal is to visualize this result using Excel and also be able to re-open it in a python script. In my company, Excel is the tool used by the analyst to visualize a csv file.

Comment: In a CSV file there is no limit save the one for the overall size of the file which on most OSs would be quite large. However, there is likely a cell-length limit in Excel which appears to be the tool you're using to view the CSV file. I suggest describing what your end goal is with this file, and perhaps one of us can suggest a better way forward.

Comment: thanks @mechanical_meat. I added an edit.

Comment: If you must use Excel, take a look at expanding the lists within those cells into separate columns as described here: https://chrisalbon.com/code/python/data_wrangling/pandas_expand_cells_containing_lists/

Comment: If you have to use Excel, it would make more sense to save the file in Excel format (.xlsx). You would then have control over column widths and cell styling. CSV files have no formatting information, just the data.